# Assigning matrix elements to variables in a data set

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Hello I'm new to Matlab.

I've written this script :

```
k2=2*pi();
z1 = 1;
z2 = 2;
z3 = 4; 
for l = linspace(0,1,11)
A = [ -1 1 1 0 ; 1 z1/z2 -z1/z2 0 ; 0 exp(-i*k2*l) exp(i*k2*l) -1 ; 0 exp(-   i*k2*l) -exp(i*k2*l) -z2/z3];
B = [ 1 ; 1 ; 0 ; 0];
D = inv(A);
C = mtimes(D,B) ;
display(C)
r = C(1,1); % this is supposed to set r = the 1,1 element in the matrix C
t = C(1,4); % see above
end
```

My idea for taking the values of r and t from C didnt appear to work. How can I do this properly?

Also I want to plot a graph of |r|,|t|, arg(r) and arg(t) for each value of l, my for loop overwrites the values of r and t? how can I either plot one point per loop or make r and t assign the new values so that they become lists of data.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab sets the first dimension of a matrix as row number (i.e. y position).
So you want `t=C(4, 1)`, as you should see that the size of C is 4x1. As a note Matlab is quite good at suppressing singleton dimensions so you could do also do `C(1)` and `C(4)`.

For your second point you want to set a particular element of r and t in each loop. This is the same as when you access at particular element of C when setting the values. For your case you can use the index `l` to determine the element. Remembering that in matlab arrays start at element 1 (not 0 as in many other languages). So you want something like `r(l+1)=C(1);` (or change l to start at 1).

In the more general case if you are not looping over an integer for some reason you may need to create a separate counter variable which you increase in the loop. Also it is good practice to preallocate such arrays when the size is known beforehand, often by `r=zeros(11, 1)` or similar (note: `zeros(11)` is an 11x11 matrix). This isn't significant in this case but can drastically increase execution time for large multi-dimensional arrays so is a good practice.